# webpack 5 source maps vendor naming/exclusion

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

i am using webpack 5 (5.53.0) and would like to produce a source maps only to my own code (excluding vendors) to a different output directory. the motivation for doing it, is i would like to always publish the source maps to a different server, which is accessible only to an internal network (not accessible to the public).

to split the code between mine and the vendors, i leveraged [`splitChunks.chunks`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkschunks)

```js
splitChunks: {
  chunks: "all"
}
```

since `devtool` does not support exclusion, i followed the [tip in webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool)

> Instead of using the `devtool` option you can also use `SourceMapDevToolPlugin` directly as it has more options. Never use both the `devtool` option and plugin together.

using [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/) i used the `filename` and `exclude` options as follows

```js
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: "maps/[name].[fullhash].bundle.js.map",
  publicPath: "https://private-server.com",
  exclude: [/vendors~main.*.bundle.js/]
})
```

when i run `webpack --mode production`, the `dist` output directory has 2 bundled files - one for mine and one for the vendors

```sh
$ ls -x1 dist/*.js dist/maps/*.js.map
dist/5.95feeb62d4fe21871683.bundle.js
dist/main.95feeb62d4fe21871683.bundle.js
dist/maps/5.95feeb62d4fe21871683.bundle.js.map
dist/maps/main.95feeb62d4fe21871683.bundle.js.map
```

as you can see, the vendors filename is named `5.95feeb62d4fe21871683.bundle.js` and since it is hashed, it changes each time the vendor packages changes. how do i define the name (such as `[name].[fullhash].bundle.js.map` [without a dedicate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67033870/1184717)) or references the name in a way that i could exclude it with `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

giving an explicit name for the split chunks, it was easy to exclude them

```js
splitChunks: {
  chunks: "all",
  cacheGroups: {
    defaultVendors: {
      filename: "vendors.[fullhash].bundle.js",
    }
  }
}
```

```js
new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
  filename: "maps/[name].[fullhash].bundle.js.map",
  publicPath: "https://private-server.com",
  exclude: [/vendors/]
})
```